# Javascript load from other file and calculating with that value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working with javascript and loading some value from another file. I'm simply just using a value in the other file:

```
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    //query the amountOfErrors variable every second
    setInterval(function()
    {
            $('#getData').load("Test3.html"); //this only contains a number like 10029138
    },1000);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='getData'></div>

<div id='calculated'>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var MachineActivityMS = document.getElementById('getData').innerHTML;
    var MachineActivityS = MachineActivityMS / 1000;  // omzetten naar secondes
    var hours = parseInt( MachineActivityS / 3600 ) % 24; // uren
    var minutes = parseInt( MachineActivityS / 60 ) % 60; // minuten
    var seconds = Math.floor(MachineActivityS) % 60; // secondes
    var resultActivity = (hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours) + ":" + (minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes) + ":" + (seconds  < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds); 

    document.write(resultActivity);
</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Sadly this results in a NaN:NaN:NaN. And when I `ParseInt()` the number it doesn't show anything at all. The calculations are correct since when I replace

```
document.getElementById('getData').innerHTML;
```

it calculates the right value (for instance 122500 = 00:20:25).

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you seem to have jquery included, why not try:

```
$('#getData').html()
```

instead of

```
document.getElementById('getData').innerHTML;
```

Inspect getData to see what it really contains in runtime. Also try to "parseInt" sooner, to force the type correctly:

```
var MachineActivityMS = parseInt($('#getData').html());
```

Update, remove the entire script-block in the body and replace the first script with this:

```
setInterval(function()
{
    $('#getData').load("Test3.html", function () {
        var MachineActivityMS = parseInt($('#getData').html());
        var MachineActivityS = MachineActivityMS / 1000;  // omzetten naar secondes
        var hours = parseInt( MachineActivityS / 3600 ) % 24; // uren
        var minutes = parseInt( MachineActivityS / 60 ) % 60; // minuten
        var seconds = Math.floor(MachineActivityS) % 60; // secondes
        var resultActivity = (hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours) + ":" + (minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes) + ":" + (seconds  < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds);
        $('#calculated').html(resultActivity);
    });
},1000);
```

Comment: I actually see whats in the div 'getData' since it's on the same page. But it seems it's not recognizing it as a int/number. How can I inspect it? I used the $('#getData').html() but still the same result.

Comment: if the response includes html code it would not be picked up by just "viewing the page", you'd have to inspect it. Right click and "inspect element" or "view source" to check that the div ONLY contains the number.

Comment: Ah right I noticed it. WITHOUT the parseInt it cointains "125000". When I use the ParseInt(), it actually shows 125000 i the div. Sadly when I use the  ParseInt, the calculation fails somehow. The div 'calculated' is empty. and shows nothing.

Comment: Another problem with the code, is that getData is set on a timer, so there is a chance that the code will be executed before it has the value. Try to calc the values only AFTER you have received a result. I'll update my answer to illustrate

Comment: No worries - a bit of trial and error but glad we finally found the root of the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

You're having

```
$('#getData').load("Test3.html");
```

run every second as soon as DOM is ready. The script below runs before that.

```
var MachineActivityMS = document.getElementById('getData').innerHTML;
var MachineActivityS = MachineActivityMS / 1000;  // omzetten naar secondes
var hours = parseInt( MachineActivityS / 3600 ) % 24; // uren
var minutes = parseInt( MachineActivityS / 60 ) % 60; // minuten
var seconds = Math.floor(MachineActivityS) % 60; // secondes
var resultActivity = (hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours) + ":" + (minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes) + ":" + (seconds  < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds); 

document.write(resultActivity);
```

and misses the `innerHTML` of `#getData` since it runs only once. I'd wrap the entire code in `setInterval` function as follows.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$('#getData').load("Test3.html");
//query the amountOfErrors variable every second
setInterval(function()
{
        $('#getData').load("Test3.html"); //this only contains a number like 10029138
        var MachineActivityMS = document.getElementById('getData').innerHTML;
        var MachineActivityS = MachineActivityMS / 1000;  // omzetten naar secondes
        var hours = parseInt( MachineActivityS / 3600 ) % 24; // uren
        var minutes = parseInt( MachineActivityS / 60 ) % 60; // minuten
        var seconds = Math.floor(MachineActivityS) % 60; // secondes
        var resultActivity = (hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours) + ":" + (minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes) + ":" + (seconds  < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds); 

        $('#calculated').html(resultActivity);
},1000);
});
```

Please note that we've used `$('#calculated').html(resultActivity);` this time. What's the point of loading the contents of the file in a div every second and doing calculations with the value *once* anyways?

Comment: The number in the test3.html is a static number now, but later on it will be a variabel so it will change. Thanks for helping me out Ozgur Bar!

Comment: We were on to the same thing, but wouldn't it be a lot safer to use the callback of "load" to only do the calculation after a result is given (like in my updated answer)?

Comment: Mackan you are right, When I use the code of Ozgur, it will first display NaN:NaN:NaN and will change after 1 sec to the right value. yours will show the right value right away :)

Comment: @Mackan alot better. (+1) :]